# Select entire row with group by on last record

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, firebird, firebird2.1

I am trying to select only last from group by but failing each time.

With this query:

```sql
SELECT
    s.NABAVNACENA, s.ROBAID, MAX(d.DATUM) AS DATUM
FROM 
    DOKUMENT d
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    STAVKA s ON s.VRDOK = d.VRDOK AND s.BRDOK = d.BRDOK
WHERE
    d.VRDOK IN (0, 11, 18, 16, 22, 1, 2, 26, 29, 30)
    AND d.DATUM >= '01.01.2021'
    AND d.DATUM <= '31.12.2021'
    AND s.ROBAID IN (39, 34)
GROUP BY 
    s.ROBAID, s.NABAVNACENA
```

I am getting these results

```
NABAVNACENA   ROBAID   DATUM
---------------------------------
149           39       01.01.2021
130           39       03.01.2021
137           39       08.01.2021
847           34       02.01.2021
820           34       03.01.2021
```

However, the desired result is only two rows grouped by `ROBAID` with max date.

In this case:

```
137     39    08.01.2021
820     34    03.01.2021
```

When I exclude `s.NABAVNACENA` from the query, it does return only these two rows, but when I include it it shows everything.

I tried a lot of things from Stack Overflow that I lost count and now I do not know what to do.

Here is the table structure

```sql
/* Table: STAVKA, Owner: SYSDBA */

CREATE TABLE "STAVKA" 
(
    "STAVKAID"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "VRDOK"      SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    "BRDOK"      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "MAGACINID"  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    "ROBAID"       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "VRSTA"        SMALLINT,
    "NAZIV"        VARCHAR(200),
    "NABCENSAPOR"  NUMERIC(15,4),
    "FAKTURNACENA" NUMERIC(15,4),
    "NABCENABT"    DOUBLE PRECISION,
    "TROSKOVI"     NUMERIC(15,4),
    "NABAVNACENA"  NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
    "PRODCENABP"   NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
    "KOREKCIJA"    DOUBLE PRECISION,
    "PRODAJNACENA" NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    "DEVIZNACENA"  NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
    "DEVPRODCENA"  NUMERIC(15,4),
    "KOLICINA"     NUMERIC(15,3) NOT NULL,
    "NIVKOL"       NUMERIC(15,3) NOT NULL,
    "TARIFAID"     VARCHAR(3),
    "IMAPOREZ"     SMALLINT,
    "POREZ"        NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    "RABAT"        NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    "MARZA"        NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    "TAKSA"        NUMERIC(15,4),
    "AKCIZA"       NUMERIC(15,2),
    "PROSNAB"      NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
    "PRECENA"      NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
    "PRENAB"       NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
    "PROSPROD"     NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
    "MTID"         VARCHAR(10),
    "PT"           CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    "ZVEZDICA"     VARCHAR(6),
    "TREN_STANJE"  NUMERIC(15,3),
    "POREZ_ULAZ"   NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    "SDATUM"       DATE,
    "DEVNABCENA"   NUMERIC(15,4),
    "POREZ_IZ"     NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
    "X4"           NUMERIC(15,3),
    "Y4"           NUMERIC(15,3),
    "Z4"           NUMERIC(15,3),
    "CENAPOAJM"    NUMERIC(15,2),
    "KGID"         INTEGER,
    "SAKCIZA"      NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "STAVKAPRIMARYKEY" PRIMARY KEY ("STAVKAID")
);
```

I would like to export data, but there are 500k rows and I do not know how it would be here.

So basically `STAVKA` is `DOCUMENT_ITEM` inside some `DOCUMENT`
That item holds `ProductID (ROBAID)`, `Price (NABAVNACENA)` and other data that are for that product in that document.

So now I want to go through all `STAVKA (DOCUMENT_ITEM)` and select last `Price (NABAVNACENA)` for each `ROBAID`.

For single one I managed to do it like this:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.STAVKAID, s.ROBAID, s.NABAVNACENA
FROM
    (SELECT FIRST 1 s.STAVKAID, d.DATUM
     FROM DOKUMENT d
     LEFT OUTER JOIN STAVKA s ON s.VRDOK = d.VRDOK AND s.BRDOK = d.BRDOK
     WHERE d.VRDOK IN (0, 11, 18, 16, 22, 1, 2, 26, 29, 30)
       AND d.DATUM >= '01.01.2021'
       AND d.DATUM <= '31.12.2021'
       AND s.ROBAID = 39
    ORDER BY DATUM DESC) AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    STAVKA s ON t1.STAVKAID = s.STAVKAID
```

It returns multiple rows, but I order them by `DATUM DESC` and select first one, that way I selected last `STAVKA` for that `ROBAID`

Since I have 4k `ROBAID`, I do not want to run this query 4k times from my code but to return whole table to it

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using? In any case, this result is entirely expected when using `GROUP BY` in this way, because including `NABAVNACENA` will make it determine the max date for each distinct value of `NABAVNACENA`.

Comment: Version 2.1. Cant go any higher, not in my power.

Comment: Will there be (at most) a single row for NABAVNACENA,  ROBAID and DATUM, or can there be multiple rows with the same DATUM for NABAVNACENA,  ROBAID?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel There could be 0.001% possibility but I didn't want to include it in this question since I have direction in my head I would try to solve it with `limit 1` or `max/min` something like that

Comment: why do you do `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `S` ? it looks rather weird seeing how `s.NABAVNACENA, s.ROBAID` are the first, most meaningful columns, and even group-making? What you plan to do with rows having NULLs in one or both of them ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the really useful things in SQL is that you can nearly always replace a tablename in a from clause with a query:

```
SELECT
    s.NABAVNACENA, x.ROBAID, x.DATUM
    from DOKUMENT d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN STAVKA s ON s.VRDOK = d.VRDOK AND s.BRDOK = d.BRDOK
    inner join
    (
      select s.ROBAID, max(d.DATUM) DATUM
      from DOKUMENT d
      LEFT OUTER JOIN STAVKA s ON s.VRDOK = d.VRDOK AND s.BRDOK = d.BRDOK
      WHERE
      d.VRDOK IN (0, 11, 18, 16, 22, 1, 2, 26, 29, 30)
      AND d.DATUM >= '01.01.2021'
      AND d.DATUM <= '31.12.2021'
      AND s.ROBAID IN (39, 34)
      GROUP BY s.ROBAID
    ) x on s.Robaid = x.robaid and d.datum = x.datum
```

The extra inner join is the query which brings in the two rows wanted but doesn't have NABAVNACENA, and uses it to restrict the original query to those two rows.

Comment: First error popped because on fourth line there is additional `from`. Second error is `Unknown column x.datum` from last row, after `and`

Comment: OK. Couple of typos: get rid of extra from line, and in the subquery I misnamed the max(d.datum) as DATUS not DATUM. I'll fix those now.

Comment: Here is response: [image](https://prnt.sc/239sjob). Not only last `NABAVNACENA` for given `ROBAID`

Comment: OK, so there are multiple rows in STAVKA which match the wanted ROBAID and DATUM. Which one of them do you want?

Comment: One that have `MAX(DATUM)`, just like in example

Comment: And that's what each of them has. Which one of those do you want? (Remember I have no idea what data is on these tables as you haven't shown us their structure.)

Comment: I will edit question with full table structure and data. Will need some time since it is huge

Comment: I suggest you look at what data is in the STAVKA table, work out what it means that each ROBAID/DATUM pair has multiple entries, and work out which entry you want to select. That's not something anyone here can do for you.

Comment: Check out edit. May be more clear

Comment: Define 'last'. Only you know what that means. max(StavkaId) maybe?

Comment: Could you please look at this image. [image](https://prnt.sc/239y6f8)

Comment: `you can nearly always replace a tablename in a from clause with a query` - you can, but it quickly becomes a mess to read. Better use CTEs, usually they are essentially the same, but more manageable.

Comment: @AleksaRistic don't do images, better put simplified tables WITH SAMPLE DATA to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0

Answer (score 0):

Can you just join the table onto itself? I would better use synthetic ID (always incrementing primary key, like AutoInc field in some databases, Generator+Trigger in FB2), but okay, let's try with dates. Just... Take care that you would not have TWO or more rows with exactly the same date in one group.

Helping would be CTE introduced in FB 2.1: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html#langrefupd21-select-cte

```
WITH DOKSTAV AS (
  SELECT 
    s.NABAVNACENA, s.ROBAID, d.DATUM
  FROM 
    DOKUMENT d, STAVKA s 
  WHERE s.VRDOK = d.VRDOK 
    AND s.BRDOK = d.BRDOK
)

SELECT
  s1.NABAVNACENA, s1.ROBAID, s1.DATUM
FROM 
  DOKSTAV s1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  DOKSTAV s2
       ON (s1.NABAVNACENA = s2.NABAVNACENA)
      AND (s1.ROBAID = s2.ROBAID)
      AND (s1.DATUM < s2.DATUM)
WHERE s2.DATUM IS NULL
```